# Создать файл pdf из web страницы на iOS

Tags: ios, безопасность, pdf, защита

Я часто создаю pdf Файлы из web страниц с английской документацией прямо в iPhone, что бы потом читать из в специальном приложении с помощью в переводе.

Все всегда без проблем работало  стандартными средствами iOS, ноне в этот раз.
Когда я попробовал проделать операцию с этой страницей , она отказалась передавать в pdf более одной страницы своего текста.

https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/technical-details/mass-transfer-transaction.html

То есть файл создаётся, но в нем всего одна страница, чего конечно же не достаточно.

Думаю это какая то защита файла на сайте.
А вы что думаете?

Comment: Ставлю на кривую вёрстку

Comment: Вряд ли у waves хреновые верстальщики

Comment: Не хреновые, просто никто не ставил им задачу сделать хорошую версию для печати. Они и не смотрели

Comment: Предположен и как это обойти теперь? Эту ошибочную защиту от скачивания)))